# How do I put a DATE type value in a String field in a Marketing Cloud data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, date, string, convert

I'm trying to do this sql query, but I'm getting an error when converting the type date to string.... I've tried using CAST/ CONVERT/ TRYCAST .. but I must be doing something around because Marketing cloud doesn't accept it:

```
SELECT
    mg.External_Id,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, Convert( DATE, MgPrd.Garantia_Fabricante), Convert( DATE,MgPrd.Data_da_Compra)) <= 100
    THEN 90       
    END AS tempo_garantia
FROM [jornada_garantias_prd_Copy] mg
INNER JOIN Ent.Master_Garantias_Jornada MgPrd
ON mg.External_Id = MgPrd.External_Id
```

Already tried:

```
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, Cast(MgPrd.Garantia_Fabricante As Date), Cast(MgPrd.Data_da_Compra As Date)) <= 100
=======================================================================================
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, Convert( Date, MgPrd.Garantia_Fabricante), Convert(Date, MgPrd.Data_da_Compra)) <= 100
```

TRY_CAST does not give an error but it also does not return the date, the final objective is to put a DATA type value in a STRING type field

This is the error: Unable to convert date and/or time from a string data type.

The fields MgPrd.Guarantee_Manufacturer and MgPrd.Data_da_Compra are of type String, I want to convert them to Date to be able to do the DATEDIFF

If anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong and how to fix it I would be very grateful

Comment: What is the data type of Garantia_Fabricante and Data_da_Compra? Text? If so, how are your dates formatted? If Date data types, why are you doing any conversion at all and not just doing a DATEDIFF on your two dates?

Comment: The fields MgPrd.Guarantee_Manufacturer and MgPrd.Data_da_Compra are of type String, I want to convert them to Date to be able to do the DATEDIFF @macca

Comment: So, how are the dates formatted in these text fields?